# How to replace back button of NavigationView from inside a UIViewControllerRepresentable?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

Consider a `UIVIewController` where a custom back button needs to be set. The reason is that the user should be presented a confirmation dialog before navigating back where they can cancel the navigation, in case the back button was tapped accidentally. If the user confirms, a method in the `UIVIewController` should be executed.

The `UIVIewController` is wrapped in a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. In a UIKit environment, the `UIVIewController` could just replace the back button like so:

```swift
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

However, since the view controller is presented in a SwiftUI `NavigationView` via a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, I tried to set it for the parent view controller:

```swift
parent?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

This doesn't work. In fact, it results in 2 back buttons, the original one to the left and the custom added one to the right:

[image]

Even if `UIViewControllerRepresentable.navigationBarItems(leading:)` is set instead, then a second button is added to to the original back button.

How can the `UIVIewController` set the custom back button?

Answer (score 0):

In the presenting view, hide the `UIViewControllerRepresentable`'s navigation bar back button. One would think that this only removes the back button, but if there is no other navigation item, the whole navigation bar is removed. To avoid this, also add an empty `Text` view:

```swift
MyViewControllerWrapper
   .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
   .navigationBarItems(leading: Text(""))
```

This removes the `NavigationView`'s back button, leaving only the custom added button. But now, the view controller cannot be dismissed programmatically anymore with:

```swift
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

So in the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` the `presentationMode` is passed to the `UIViewController`:

```swift
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
...
viewController.presentationMode = presentationMode
```

Then in the `UIViewController`, when the back button is tapped, the view is dismissed with:

```swift
presentationMode?.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

It works, but I'm sure there's a more elegant solution out there.